# With Selenium 3.8.1, Firefox, Chrome, and IE driver capabilities are deprecated.

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, desiredcapabilities

Can anybody advise how to remove warnings from FirefoxDriver (capabilities) and 
ChromeDriver (capabilities)?

FIREFOX
    {
        @Override
        public DesiredCapabilities getDesiredCapabilities ()
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox ();
            return capabilities;
        }

```
    @Override
    public WebDriver getWebDriverObject (DesiredCapabilities capabilities)
    {   

        return new FirefoxDriver (capabilities);
    }
},

CHROME_Original
{
    @Override
    public DesiredCapabilities getDesiredCapabilities ()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ();
        capabilities.setCapability ("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList ("--no-default-browser-check"));
        HashMap<String, String> chromePreferences = new HashMap<String, String> ();
        chromePreferences.put ("profile.password_manager_enabled", "false");
        capabilities.setCapability ("chrome.prefs", chromePreferences);
        return capabilities;
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver getWebDriverObject (DesiredCapabilities capabilities)
    {
        return new ChromeDriver (capabilities);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setCapability("chrome.switches",Arrays.asList("--no-default-browser-check")); 
    HashMap<String, Boolean>chromePreferences = new HashMap<>(); 
    chromePreferences.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
    options.setCapability("chrome.prefs", chromePreferences); 
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The ChromeDriver constructor now takes in ChromeOptions object as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating `DesiredCapabilities` directly has been deprecated in favor of type-safe “Options” classes (`FirefoxOptions` `InternetExplorerOptions`, etc). This has the advantage of helping you avoid setting incorrect or invalid values for the driver. You get rid of the deprecation warnings by changing your code to use the newer, safer construct.